# How to show posts containing only the selected taxonomy terms in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm trying to add a taxonomy filter form to a page using a $_GET method to push the selected taxonomy terms to the `tax_query`. If more terms are selected then this should return only the posts containing those exact terms. Instead I get all posts that have at least 1 of the selected terms.

This is a single array so `'relation' => 'AND'` won't work here. So instead I tried setting the `'operator'` parameter to `'AND'` but this gives me no results at all after selecting any of the terms. I even tried pushing a `foreach` loop inside the query to create a new `tax_query` array for each term hoping to get the `relation` parameter to do the work instead. But this didn't work and actually seemed like a bad idea.

This is my current query setup:

```
get_template_part('partials/blog', 'filter');

$paged = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );

$blog_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'date',
  'paged' => $paged,
  'posts_per_page' => 2
);
if(isset( $_GET['category'] ) ) {
  $blog_args['tax_query'] = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'category',
        'field' => 'slug',
        'terms' => $_GET['category'],
        'operator' => 'AND'
      ),
  );
}

$blog_query = new WP_Query($blog_args);
```

If a category is selected by the user that value get pushed to `'terms'` as an array.

I expected the `'operator'` parameter to act like the `'relation'` parameter but this doesn't seem to be the case or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Did you test the output of your terms array?

Comment: @justkidding96 Yep I tested this with `var_dump()` to check if it actually returns an `array()` of the selected terms. This appears to be working as it should.

Comment: Please  remove 'relation' and 'operator' parameter because no need of it.And check once i guess it works.

Comment: @SohilChamadia This changes nothing. `'relation'` has no effect at the moment but will be necessary once I add more taxonomies. The `'operator'` does affect the query but somehow `'AND'` isn't working as I'd expect it to work. I already tried removing it or changing it's value to any of the other options but so far no dice.

Comment: Did you try to use ‘IN’ instead of ‘AND’?

Comment: @justkidding96 I did and I even tried `'NOT IN'` just to check for unexpected behaviour. The only value that's not doing what I expect it to do is `'AND'`. If the terms array looks like this `array( term #1, term #2 )` I'd expect it to only return posts marked with `term #1 AND term #2` if the `'operator'` is set to `'AND'`.

Comment: Is the slug of your taxonomy correct?

Comment: @justkidding96 I'm sure it is. I mean it has to be otherwise I wouldn't even be able to get the terms to work.