# Get all category name of a taxonomy dinamically in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, addition

i have to do a project for a friend and i need to know if It is possibile to retrieve all category name of a taxonomy dinamically in wordpress .If It is possibile how can i do?

Comment: Did you already searched on the forum? Because there are many similar questions like yours.

Comment: I have searched but I haven't found a specific answer for my scope

Comment: Watch this thread for more information: https://stackoverflow.com/q/55981213/4582744

Comment: I don't understand what i have to put in attributes:field and terms.I don't understand the difference between this two

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it! First add below codes at the end of function.php file:

```
function current_cat() { 
    global $post;
    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
     $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' . '&depth=1' );
      else
      $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' . '&depth=1' );
    if ( $childpages ) {
    $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }
    return $string;
}
add_shortcode('currentcat', 'current_cat');
```

Then you can use it almost anywhere by calling shortcode name:

```
 [currentcat]
```

Comment: Thanks,great!a question:is it possible to do this thing using get_terms?

Comment: No problem. I've not try that for this case. But I have used this shortcode in this website and works nice, you can see categories of current menu above posts:
https://teram-packaging.com/en/teram-group/social-responsibilities

Comment: I want to take advantage of your courtesy:):)Is it possible to do this:terms => all...to retrieve all categories with tax_query?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this function get_terms()

```
$taxonomies = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'taxonomy_name'
) );

if ( !empty($taxonomies) ) :
    foreach( $taxonomies as $category ) {
      print_r($category);
    }
endif;
```

for more reference https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/ ,  also this tutorial might be help you [Show Custom Taxonomy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2lyKqYw4VxA&t=131s)